# Android-Java: location.getTime() returns UTC-1 instead of UTC if current timezone is on 'daylight savings'

Tags: android, gps, location

```
location.getTime() ->GPS-Listener
```

returned the `longint-value`: *1441279754000*.

As per http://currentmillis.com/: *1441279754000* stands for
'*Thu Sep 3 2015 11:29:14 UTC*', although the current time was
'*Thu Sep 3 2015 1**2**:29:14 UTC*'

Current timezone on the device:
`GMT+2:00, Central European Summer Time` (daylight-savings)

Changing the timezone to:
`GMT+4:00 Moscow` (no daylight-savings):
**->** `location.getTime()` returned a correct value.

Maybe a bug in Android 4.4.2; device is 'Wiko Rainbow 4G':

If current timezone is a daylight-savings-timezone, then a wrong value (UTC-1) is returned.

Does anyone knows a workaround or am I doing wrong?

---

More info:

Using:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
...
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    long millis = location.getTime();
    long deltaToDeviceTime = millis - System.currentTimeMillis();
    ...
}}
```

means, that the `gps-timestamp` 'millis' just arrived - is fresh.

While the test-program is running, I go to

> Android-main-menu -> Settings -> Date & time -> Select time zone

and change the timezone from
a 'daylight-savings-timezone' to
a 'non-daylight-savings-timezone' and back.

With 'non-daylight-savings-timezone' the value of deltaToDeviceTime is
about 2000 == two seconds -> correct.

With 'daylight-savings-timezone' the value of deltaToDeviceTime is
about 3600000 == one hour -> wrong.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?